# Is there any multi-touch graphics tablet with Linux drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, tablet

After watching the absolutely amazing [10/GUI video](http://10gui.com), I have been dying to try to implement something like this. I can do the software side quite easily, but I don't have the hardware.

The [Wacom Bamboo Fun](http://www.wacom.com/bamboo/bamboo_fun.php) would work, but the Linux drivers don't support the multi-touch features.

Microsoft's "UnMouse Pad" looks like the *perfect* solution, but it is not commercially available yet.

Are there any similar devices that would work? Alternatively, is there a way to build a DIY version? (It is fairly easy to build a multi-touch display with a webcam and IR LEDs, but it would not be pressure sensitive. Does anyone have any info on how the UnMouse Pad works and if it is possible to build one?)

**EDIT:** I should clarify that I don't want a multi-touch display. I want the sensor to be separate from the display. If that sounds crazy, watch the 10/GUI video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Linux Wacom Project](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/) supports the Wacom Bamboo and Bamboo Fun tablets, which have multi-touch.

I ordered a Bamboo Pen and Touch and it works great with the latest drivers, but I had to compile it myself since it's not in Ubuntu's repositories yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Tuxmobil](http://tuxmobil.org/tablet_unix.html) There's a fairly comprehensive list of links to pages including sites where people have setup linux on a wide variety of tablets using different *nixes. They ware written in a wide variety of usefulness too.  Some require some detailed knowledge of the OS used.

Scroll down to the bottom on that page & there's section "TouchScreen Drivers"

There is a description of how to set multi-touch up in linux at the [ENAC Interactive Computing lab](http://lii-enac.fr/en/projects/shareit/xorg.html)

Update:
Thanks for reminding me to read %%$&##! question before I whip off an answer....

Two links you may find interesting:
 1. A page on how to build a "[5 minute, dirt cheap multiyouch pad](http://hacknmod.com/hack/5-minute-dirt-cheap-multitouch-pad/)".  It says a windows library touchlib is required, but it's written in C++, so ...
 2.  Multigesture.net has some [ubuntu-based compiling instructions](http://www.multigesture.net/articles/touchlib-compiling-instructions-ubuntu/).

There's also a [Natural Interface Users Group](http://wiki.nuigroup.com/Applications#Linux) site.  Small, but promising.

Comment: As far as I can tell, those are just about multi-touch *displays*, not multi-touch pads (i.e. the sensor is separated from the display, as in 10/GUI). Also, that is just about the software. I'm writing my own software anyway, so that doesn't really help. This is quite frustrating since it should be a lot easier and cheaper to create a multi-touch sensor when it doesn't have to be transparent...

Answer (score 0):

You can code it as a Compiz plugin like this one:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00A0bgupsX4&feature=player_embedded

Alternatively you can follow what is being done in the "official" Linux community (Ubuntu, Red Hat etc) by using the MPX+multitouchd driver to the Xorg.

Comment: I'm not worried about the software part. I can deal with that. I'm just looking for the hardware, because I don't have any.